# Network errors while doing reviews

Tags: discussion, review, firefox, proxy

Since some time today, doing reviews is a very shaky operation; every second or third review when I click on the action button (regardless of what button, or what review queue), I get the loading animation, but nothing ever happens.

When running Firebug while doing so it gives me the following error messages:

```
GET http://stackoverflow.com/flags/questions/19376771/close/popup?_=1381844073337
200 OK
    301ms   

GET http://stackoverflow.com/posts/popup/close/suggest-originals/19376771?_=1381844075452   
200 OK
    276ms   

GET http://stackoverflow.com/posts/popup/close/searc...-a-hex-string-to-byte-array-in-c&_=1381844076684
200 OK
    318ms   

POST http://stackoverflow.com/flags/questions/19376771/close/add
"NetworkError: 502 Proxy Error ( The s...43 for SSL requests.  ) - http://sockets.ny.stackexchange.com/"

socket...nge.com
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://sockets.ny.stackexchange.com/.


..."wss://")&&(a=("https:"===document.location.protocol?"wss://":"ws://")+a);if("We...

full.e...ae5f38a (line 13)

"NetworkError: 502 Proxy Error ( The s...43 for SSL requests.  ) - http://sockets.ny.stackexchange.com/"

socket...nge.com
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://sockets.ny.stackexchange.com/.


..."wss://")&&(a=("https:"===document.location.protocol?"wss://":"ws://")+a);if("We...
```

My first idea was that there is a problem because I am behind a proxy, but what confuses me is that this does not happen every time but only every second or third; also I didn't have this problem in the past and nothing changed concerning the proxy configuration.

Is the problem on my side or is this a server side problem? This happens on Firefox 24.0